# ssh-agent / ssh-add error: could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I type in `ssh-agent` and get the following back:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-GqdeT074HLRJ/agent.4670; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_ID=4671; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 4671;
```

I then type in `ssh-add privkey.pem` and get the following:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I tried adding `sudo` before each of those commands, as well, but got near identical output.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You’re supposed to execute the output that you get back from `ssh-agent`, like this: `eval $(ssh-agent)`

Then your environment is set up for `ssh-add` to connect to the agent.

Comment: I tried `sudo eval $(ssh-agent)` and it said `sudo: eval: command not found`. I tried `eval $(sudo ssh-agent)` and it said `Agent pid 4735` and then, after both of those, `ssh-add` still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: never mind - doing `sudo bash` and then doing all that got the job done. thanks!

Comment: "eval `ssh-agent`" also works. I didn't need any sudo.

Comment: doing eval and then ssh-add still did not work for me, any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the following syntax:

```
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add && echo Do some stuff here.'
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution:

run below command OR add to .bashrc file

## exec ssh-agent bash

## ssh-add  [key path]

Comment: (1) Two solutions have already been posted, and one has been accepted as correct.  Does yours have any advantage over those earlier ones?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. (2) Do you really believe that it’s a good idea to `exec bash` from within `.bashrc`?  Have you tried it?  Before you do, think hard about what will happen.  (Hint: what does a new bash process do when it starts?)  If you do dare to try it, you might want to make sure that you have another shell window open.